# Python:How do I use "or" in a regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

I have the text below :

```
text='apples and oranges apples and grapes apples and lemons'
```

and I want to use regular expressions to achieve something like below:

'apples and oranges'

'apples and lemons'

I tried this `re.findall('apples and (oranges|lemons)',text)` , but it doesn't work.

**Update:** If the 'oranges' and 'lemons' were a list : `new_list=['oranges','lemons']`, how could I go to (?:'oranges'|'lemons') without typing them again ?

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Hmm. Works for me. You should clarify exactly what you have tried, and exactly what the output was.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`re.findall()`: If one or more groups are present in the pattern, return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern has more than one group.

Try this:

```
re.findall('apples and (?:oranges|lemons)',text)
```

`(?:...)` is a non-capturing version of regular parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

What you've described should work:

In example.py:

```
import re
pattern = 'apples and (oranges|lemons)'
text = "apples and oranges"
print re.findall(pattern, text)
text = "apples and lemons"
print re.findall(pattern, text)
text = "apples and chainsaws"
print re.findall(pattern, text)
```

Running `python example.py`:

```
['oranges']
['lemons']
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a non-capturing group `re.search('apples and (?:oranges|lemons)',text)`?